# How to pipe a command result to a -<character><argument> option? (Without spaces)

Tags: bash, command, pipe, head

I have this set of piped commands:

```
grep -n '*' file.txt | head -n1 | awk -F\: '{print $1-1;}'
```

It tells me the previous line to that where it first find asterisks.
Now I want to get the previous lines piping that to:

```
head -n<that previous line number>
```

Head requires a number following immediately the -n argument, without spaces, for example:

```
head -n4
```

How can I do that?  It just won't accept adding

```
| head -n
```

at the end of the set of commands.
My searches have been fruitless.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want back-ticks to substitute the value:

```
head -n`grep -n '*' file.txt | head -n1 | awk -F\: '{print $1-1;}'` file.txt
```

Or possibly something similar on multiple lines:

```
LINENO=`grep -n '*' file.txt | head -n1 | awk -F\: '{print $1-1;}'`
head -n${LINENO} file.txt
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot for your prompt answer!!

Comment: I suggest to use $() instead of backticks; $() nests and is easier to distinguish than the three types of single quotes which you can find on your keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just do:

```
awk -- '{if (!/*/) print $0; else exit}' file.txt
```

or this, which is faster:

```
awk -- '/*/ {exit}; {print}' file.txt
```

Comment: That's an excellent idea, I will better use this, thanks!
However, for the sake of consistency with the posed question, I will keep accepting the first answer by Douglas and Aaron as the valid ones. (Joe's answer also works). Sadly, I still can't rate answers!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could also use xargs. Something like:

```
grep -n '*' file.txt | head -n1 | awk -F\: '{print $1-1;}' | xargs -I % head -n% file.txt
```